# HTTP Post request with tab delimited field

Tags: http, parsing, post, asp-classic, csv

I've been asked to set up a web service for account creation. The inbound HTTP Post request contains a single formatted field containing tab delimited fields with a header line wrapped in tags.

Here's a sample:

```
accountRequest=<NewUser>
userName password fName lName
ABC123 wzbtw88g Joe Bloggs
</NewUser>
```

Can anyone help me understand how to parse it with Classic ASP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extract the values into a string and do something like this

```
<%

str="userName   password    fName   lName   ABC123  wzbtw88g    Joe Bloggs"

arr=split(str,vbTab)

for i=lbound(arr) to ubound(arr)
    response.write i & "=" & arr(i) &"<BR>"
next
```

%>

Comment: +1 Close enough, although it doesn't show how to handle the strange `<NewUser>` tag in form field.

Comment: Thanks, and yes, the <newUser> tag is what I can't seem to find solutions for.

Comment: just use a "replace" function to get rid of it.