# Parsing POST request with unexpected URL encoding

Tags: parsing, post, vbscript, wireshark

This question follows [an earlier one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026654/http-post-request-with-tab-delimited-field).

Here is some code that reproduces the problem:

POST:

```
str = "accountRequest=<NewUser>" & vbLf & _
"Hello" & vbTab & "World" & vbLf & _
"</NewUser>"


Set objHTTP = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")
objHTTP.open "POST", "service.asp", False 
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objHTTP.send str

response.Write(objHTTP.responseText)

Set objHTTP = Nothing
```

service.asp:

```
function w (str)
response.Write(str & "<br>")
end function

str = request.Form("accountRequest")

w(str)
w("Tabs: "& InStr(str,vbTab))
w("Lines: "& InStr(str,vbLf))
```

output:

```
HelloWorld
Tabs: 0
Lines: 0
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Are you posting from a Windows machine to a Linux machine?

Comment: It's going to a Windows machine from what appears to be a Linux machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out that ASP `Request.Form` method doesn't preserve tabs if they're in the "\t" format (as opposed to URL encoded). However, PHP's `$_POST` does.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 Replace(Request.Form("accountRequest"), vbLF, vbCRLF))
```

Or:

```
 Replace(Request.Form("accountRequest"), vbLF, "<br>"))|
```

Depending on where you're displaying it, either should work.

Or possibly this:

```
Function URLDecode(sConvert)
  Dim aSplit
  Dim sOutput
  Dim I
  If IsNull(sConvert) Then
     URLDecode = ""
     Exit Function
  End If

  ' convert all pluses to spaces
  sOutput = REPLACE(sConvert, "+", " ")

  ' next convert %hexdigits to the character
  aSplit = Split(sOutput, "%")

  If IsArray(aSplit) Then
    sOutput = aSplit(0)
    For I = 0 to UBound(aSplit) - 1
      sOutput = sOutput & _
        Chr("&H" & Left(aSplit(i + 1), 2)) &_
        Right(aSplit(i + 1), Len(aSplit(i + 1)) - 2)
    Next
  End If

  URLDecode = sOutput
End Function
```

From here: http://www.aspnut.com/reference/encoding.asp

If they are coming across the wire as the actual "\" and "n" characters, you can do a replace on those characters with the appropriate vbCRLF and vbTAB constants.

Comment: Thanks but I'm afraid that didn't do it. I still get:
`<NewUser>userNamepasswordfNamelNameABC123wzbtw88gJoeBloggs</NewUser>`

It's as though it doesn't recognize the line feeds or tabs..

Comment: It seems that as soon as ASP/VB handles the POST using the Request method, the line feeds and tabs are escaped.

Comment: Hi greener, I updated my answer. You can possibly use that to decode the URL string?

Comment: Wireshark is showing the "\" and "n" characters but when I request them using the ASP Request method, they are not there so I can't do replace. I can even see in the hex view the "0a"s and "09"s.

Comment: You can do a For or Do loop and loop through each character, then print out each character value with Asc() to see their ASCII values. You can then do a Replace() with the Chr() value that's reported by the Asc() function to get the desired result if none of those other suggestions work. I can add an example if you aren't sure how to do this.

Comment: Sorry natemrice. Tried your suggestion but the characters are simply not coming through. There just seems to be a problem between what Wireshark is showing and the Request.Form method.